# Returning a BOOL value from alertview delegate method: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I added a tabbar controller on MainWindow.xib which is displaying 5 tabs and have the tab bar controller's delegate method: `shouldSelectViewController` in my app delegate which returns boolean value (YES or NO).

In this delegate method, I am showing an alert to the user (if user is going from tab 1 to any other tab). This alert contains 2 buttons: OK and Cancel.

If user clicks on OK, then I want the delegate method to return YES (so that user can go to other tabs) and if user has selected Cancel (in case he wants to stay on tab 1 only), then I want the method to return NO.

So, basically i want the shouldSelectViewController method to stop executing till the time alert is present on screen. Is there any way I can return a BOOL from my alert view's delegate method which may, in turn, be returned by shouldSelectViewController OR any threading solution which may be of use for this situation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

in .h

```
UIViewController *tmpController;
```

in .m

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
tmpController = viewController;
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
return NO;
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = tmpController;
}
}
```